# Change ImageView BackgroundResource in listview onItemSelected Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I use an efficientAdapter to populate mylistview as shown below:

Comment: please give me your ecran_multiple_row.xml full code..

Comment: ok check question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. I cleaned up and simplified your code.

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<SearchTracks> mSearchTracks;
    private ResultatMultiple mResultatMultiple;
    private int mSelectedPosition;

    public EfficientAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<SearchTracks> searchTracks) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mSearchTracks = searchTracks;
    }

    public EfficientAdapter(ResultatMultiple resultatMultiple){
        mResultatMultiple = resultatMultiple ;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSearchTracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecran_multiple_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.indexTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txIndex);
            holder.titleTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txSTitle);
            holder.buttonOnOffImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btOnOFF);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        int index = position + 1;
        holder.indexTextView.setText((index <= 9 ? "0" : "") + Integer.toString(index));
        holder.titleTextView.setText(mSearchTracks.get(position).getTitle());

        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_odd);
        }else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_even);
        }

        if(mSearchTracks.size() == 1 || position == mSelectedPosition) {
            holder.buttonOnOffImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.air_radio_button_rouge);
        }else {
            holder.buttonOnOffImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.air_deezer_check);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView indexTextView;
        public TextView titleTextView;
        public ImageView buttonOnOffImageView;
    }
}
```

Now in your onClick listener you can call `listAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);` and then `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to reload your table.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to maintain the scrolling position and have a check that your ImageView of ListView row don't inter-change the resource.

Inside your Adapter's `getView()` class use

```
vi.setTag(R.id.btOnOFF, holder.btOnOFF);
```

And then fetch it inside `onItemClick()` using `getTag()`

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.btOnOFF);
imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.air_radio_button_rouge);
```

For further reference you can check my [blog post](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Comment: can you provide me with a sample based on my question please ?

Comment: already given a link to my blog in the answer itself which has complete example :-)