# How to get position of a button in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview with Textview, ImageView and Button ,what i would like is to change the background of the button when its clicked , i hope you understunded my issue .

This is the Adapter .

```
package com.example.mahdi.chat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import circleview.CircleImageView;

public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = FeedListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private String URL = "http://10.0.3.2/social/like.php";
private String user_id;
private Button like,comment;

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
FeedItem item;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems, String user_id) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void refresh(List<FeedItem> newlist) {
    feedItems.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public List<FeedItem> getData() {
    return feedItems;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

   final  TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.status);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.url);
    CircleImageView profilePic = (CircleImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.image);


    TextView nbr_likes = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_likes);
    TextView nbr_comments = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_comments);


    item = feedItems.get(position);




    like =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    comment =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);




    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            item = feedItems.get(position);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("post_id", item.getId());
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            Toast.makeText(activity, item.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(activity, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    URL,params , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {

                        parseJsonFeed(response);


                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);



        }

    });



    comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }


    });

    name.setText(item.getName());

   nbr_likes.setText(item.getNbrLikes()+ " Likes");
    nbr_comments.setText(item.getNbrComments() + " Comments");


    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // url is null, remove from the view
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}


private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    int success;
    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "erreur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

FeedItem Class

```
package com.example.mahdi.chat;

public class FeedItem {

private String id,name, status, image, profile_img, time, url,nbr_likes,nbr_comments;

public FeedItem() {
}

public FeedItem(String id, String name, String image, String status,
                String profilePic, String timeStamp, String url,String nbr_likes,String nbr_comments) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.status = status;
    this.profile_img = profilePic;
    this.time = timeStamp;
    this.url = url;
    this.nbr_likes = nbr_likes;
    this.nbr_comments = nbr_comments;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImge() {
    return image;
}

public void setImge(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getProfilePic() {
    return profile_img;
}

public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
    this.profile_img = profilePic;
}

public String getTimeStamp() {
    return time;
}

public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
    this.time = timeStamp;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getNbrLikes() {
    return nbr_likes;
}

public void setNbrLikes(String nbr_likes) {
    this.nbr_likes = nbr_likes;
}

public String getNbrComments() {
    return nbr_comments;
}

public void setNbrComments(String nbr_comments) {
    this.nbr_comments = nbr_comments;
}
```

}

The problem is the button Like , i would like to change the drawable of the button when its clicked .Thanks.

**EDIT :**

```
package com.example.mahdi.chat;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import circleview.CircleImageView;

public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = FeedListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private String URL = "http://10.0.3.2/social/like.php";
private String user_id;
private Button like,comment;

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
FeedItem item;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems, String user_id) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void refresh(List<FeedItem> newlist) {
    feedItems.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public List<FeedItem> getData() {
    return feedItems;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

   final  TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.status);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.url);
    CircleImageView profilePic = (CircleImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.image);


    TextView nbr_likes = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_likes);
    TextView nbr_comments = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_comments);


    item = feedItems.get(position);




    like =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
    comment =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);



    like.setTag(position);

    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

            like.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


            item = feedItems.get(position);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("post_id", item.getId());
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            Toast.makeText(activity, item.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(activity, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    URL,params , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {

                        parseJsonFeed(response);


                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);



        }

    });



    comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            item = feedItems.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, Comment.class);
            i.putExtra("user_id",item.getId());
            i.putExtra("name",item.getName());
            i.putExtra("image",item.getImge());
            i.putExtra("status",item.getStatus());
            i.putExtra("profile_img",item.getProfilePic());
            i.putExtra("time",item.getTimeStamp());
            i.putExtra("url",item.getUrl());
            i.putExtra("nbr_likes",item.getNbrLikes());
            i.putExtra("nbr_comments",item.getNbrComments());
            activity.startActivity(i);


        }


    });

    name.setText(item.getName());

   nbr_likes.setText(item.getNbrLikes()+ " Likes");
    nbr_comments.setText(item.getNbrComments() + " Comments");


    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // url is null, remove from the view
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}


private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    int success;
    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "erreur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the button is within the listview.
First define a click listener on the button in the getView function of the adapter:

```
likebutton.setOnClickListener(likeButtonClickListener);
```

Then define the onclick listener:

```
private OnClickListener likeButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
        ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
        final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
    }
};
```

There is also another way by setting the tag in the getView function:

```
likebutton.setTag(position);
likebutton.setOnClickListener(likeButtonClickListener);
```

In the button click listener, we will get the tag and find the position value.

```
private OnClickListener likeButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
    }
};
```

**Edit:** to explain the solution of the link i mentioned in comments.
He declares a final boolean variable *mHighlightedPositions* which provides info if the highlighted position in the listview is selected or not.
If this variable returns *true* the line in the listview is selected, so what you can do is.

Declare a variable "NUM_OF_ITEMS" as integer and the "mHighlightedPositions" as a boolean in your adapter:

```
private int NUM_OF_ITEMS;
private final boolean[] mHighlightedPositions = new boolean[NUM_OF_ITEMS];
```

With this you can define if a item in the listview is selected or not and apply the background/color to your button like he did:

```
...
 if(mHighlightedPositions[position]) {
        holder.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_yellow_star_large);
    }else {
        holder.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
...
```

If you want to follow his example you also need to declare a ViewHolder.

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
```

The position of the items will be returned by the *position* variable:

```
int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
```

See below example from the link:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = (Integer)view.getTag(); // gets current position
    Log.d(TAG, "Button row pos click: " + position);
    ...
      ...
    if(mHighlightedPositions[position]) { // current position is given
        button.setBackgroundResource(0);
        mHighlightedPositions[position] = false;
    }else {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_yellow_star_large);
        mHighlightedPositions[position] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but after getting the position , how can i use it to change background of a specific button . i just do like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like1); ? or i need to do something else ?

Comment: @Frank, if you just want to change the color then: likebutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); If you want to use drawable then: likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_image);
Pls accept the answer if this helped you.

Comment: i think i have a problem with the position with i click on like another button like get the black color not the one i clicked , do you know where the problem come from?

Comment: Hmm, I see you have two buttons defines (like, comment). I`ll edit my answer 1 moment.

Comment: Its 2 buttons but its only one button that i want to change his color .for all my other items (Texview and ImageView) , I have the class feeditem and to get the value at a position i do : item = feedItems.get(position); item.getId() for example ,the only problem i have is with buttons .

Comment: You get the position but if you change the color, the color of both buttons change right?

Comment: I think you should get the picture by now, also see this answer for some more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073990/android-change-button-background-in-listview-row-with-onclick

Comment: I think the solution in the link that you send will work but i dont know what did he mean by private final boolean[] mHighlightedPositions = new boolean[NUM_OF_ITEMS]; How can i know the number of my items?

Comment: @Frank, pls see my edited answer, i hope this helps you now to understand what is ment.

Comment: Thank you, it works but just when i give the number of my item in NUM_OF_ITEMS but how can i get my number of items dynamically?

Comment: You don`t , it will get the correct line by this: int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
See my edit. Kindly accept my answer as this should work now.
Thank you.

Comment: This is the error that he gives me when i use exacly what you said : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 .as i said before NUM_OF_ITEMS is the number of items so it need to be initialized to make this work .

Comment: So count the items in your listview and intialize the NUM_OF_ITEMS with its value.

Comment: That's what is said to you before it works when i give the number of my items but its a list of news in my app the number change everytime i need some way to get the number of items dynamically .

Comment: Then you should count "lstView.getAdapter().getCount() " the items and pass that value everytime you intialize your listview/or fill it with new "news".